# iOS: Use case: Navigation Bar with Bar Buttons versus normal Buttons?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller which is embedded in a navigation controller. The navigation bar (from the `UINavigationController`).

The most part of the view controller will be covered by a table view.
The navigation bar's area is filled with the title and the usual navigation buttons.
I need to display some additional buttons.
I was wondering if I place these buttons at the bottom as normal `UIButtons`, or if I should place a second navigation bar on the bottom and place a few `UIBarButtons` in it?

Is it possible to have a second navigation bar? Does it make sense?

Or can a view controller only have a single navigation bar? If yes, what would be the use case for a navigation bar versus a navigation controller?

Comment: Are you using a xib, storyboard or are you wanting to show the toolbar programmatically?

Comment: using storyboards, and I don't want to show the toolbar programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the amount and the functionality of the buttons. In principle I'd avoid having two lines of buttons under each other, especially if their functionality is not related. So generally I would opt for a button area on the bottom of the screen.

A case where it might make sense to have a second "navigation bar" is when the top bar displays a "Menu" button on the left side, and the scone bar under it has a "back" button on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `UINavigationController` it comes with a toolbar that is displayed at the bottom of the screen.  It's hidden by default.

You can add `UIBarButtonItem` buttons to this toolbar.

To display the `UINavigationController` toolbar, edit the storyboard, tap Navigation Controller and look in the right pane and check "Shows Toolbar".